# adverb + prepositional phrase or prepositional phrase + prepositional phrase

Tags: prepositional-phrases

**A man in a black suit**

Can I say "**a man warmly in a black suit**" (a man who warmly wears a black suit) or "**a man in a black suit like gentlemen**" (a man who wears a black suit like gentlemen)?

For your information, I made these sentences on my own.

Comment: What would "warmly"modify there? Nothing. So, it does not work. Also, we would not say a man wears a suit warmly. We do say: People dress warmly in winter. OR They greeted their guests warmly. You need to look these up before posting. I am downvoting this question.

Comment: An adverb has to modify a verb. 'A man _dressed_ warmly in a thick sweater'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first doesn't make sense ("warmly" doesn't work), but with other adverbs that would be possible.

> a man partially in a black suit.

The second is fine but "gentleman" needs an article

> a man in a black suit like a gentleman

There is some ambiguity there, it's unclear from the syntax if the man is like a gentleman or the suit is like a gentleman.  Of course, it must be that the man is like a gentleman, for pragmatic reasons.

Comment: I used "a man in a black suit like a gentleman" to describe a man wears a black suit like a gentleman wears a black suit. Like "I fly like a butterfly." "I wear a black suit like a gentleman."

Comment: I want to know why "warmly" doesn't work.

Comment: A man beautifully in a suit, a man warmly in a suit, a man nicely in a suit.

Comment: I think "warmly" needs a verb to modify.  In fact all these examples would be better with a  verb.  So "a man dressed warmly in a black suit" or "a man wearing a black suit like a gentleman" are much better sentences

Comment: @Faint A man **wearing** a dark suit like a gentlemam. The present simple is for something general or that is repetitive.

Comment: @JamesK - Surely the implication is 'a black suit of the kind a gentleman would wear'?

Comment: Yes, that too., though perhaps "like a gentleman's"